How to set data labels in the center of bubbles in a bubble chart ApexCharts?
I'm working on a bubble chart using ApexCharts and I'm having trouble centering the data labels in the middle of each bubble. I've searched the documentation and found options to set the horizontal alignment but nothing specific for vertical alignment.
Here's a sample data file I'm using for testing: Sample Data File.
I've set up a sandbox for testing: Sandbox.
Here is what the chart looks like using the sample data file
I want each data label to be centered both horizontally and vertically within its corresponding bubble. Right now, in the image, the labels are only centered horizontally but not vertically, it is slightly offsetted below.
Some of the things I tried is:

Using offsetY, which does move the labels but affects all bubbles uniformly, not centering them within each individual bubble.
Using offsetY as an array or setting it via a custom function didn't yield the desired results, it just moved all the data labels to the top of the graph.


The datalabels are automatically centered vertically but it seems they don't take into account multiple lines. If you use one line labels (don't split(" ")) the labels from the sample file look OK. To vertically center a two-line datalabel you'd have to set offsetY to -fontSize/2 (i.e., offsetY: -8) (- half line spacing that might amount to a pixel or two, but it's safe to be left out if the labels are top-heavy).

If you want to control individual point's offsetY, distributed: true doesn't seem to work with offsetY, only with styles, so the only solution I can think of is to put each point in its own series.

For the data I am working with, I need to put the data labels into multiple indentations (ranges from 1-4 lines), so setting offsetY won't be a solution that is too effective. I will try to put each point in its series but it feels like a very tedious solution for something as simple as setting the vertical alignment of the data labels.

I identified the point in the source code where taking into account the number of lines could have been implemented and is missing, in the function DataLabels#dataLablesCorection. The textRects.height is computed correctly but it's not used to adjust the position of the datalabel, y. A simple hacky correction could be easily implemented by overriding that method, but unfortunately, apexcharts does not expose the class DataLabels - I searched a lot and found no way to get hold of it in user code.

An alternative approach that I saw frequently used on SVG based libraries is to access and change the attributes of the relevant SVG elements after they were added to the DOM. In your case, targeting '.apexcharts-datalabels text' works; there's a version of that as function centerTextLabels at the end of this codepen that is a simplified, static-data version of your sandbox. It has to be called each each time the chart is updated, and it might need some extending in case there are other forms of data labels that I have not taken into consideration

I've tested with the data labels I am working with and it works as intended! Thank you so much :D.
